# Optimal table design for ELO system

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I'm trying to create elo system using django with postgresql.

Below description is a system what I imagined.

Elo table sorted by Date field. Table have two player's elo data field.

When an **new game** created, calculated elo data will accumulated on table directly. This works when a game is newest.

```
      Elo Table

Date     | 2022-04-01
Player A | 1015.0 (Win)
Player B | 985.0

Date     | 2022-04-02
Player A | 1021.0 (Win)
Player B | 979.0
                   <--------------------+
// new game created                     |
// this data will be located at here ---+
Date     | 2022-04-03          
Player A | 1012.0       
Player B | 988.0  (Win)
```

However, when **past game** created, not familiar situation occured.

First, calculate elo data with previous data for current game. Second, all elo data what following this game will be updated.

```
      Elo Table

Date     | 2022-04-01
Player A | 1015.0 (Win)
Player B | 985.0
                     <-----------------------+
Date     | 2022-04-03                        |
Player A | 1021.0 (Win)  (this value will be |
Player B | 979.0           re-calculated.)   |
                                             |
// past game created.                        |
// this data will be located at here --------+
// all data after this will be updated.
Date     | 2022-04-02            
Player A | 1002.0       
Player B | 998.0  (Win)
```

I cannot find other solution. Also I think this solution isn't perfect because when you created past game, **you should re-calculate massive elo data** if you have large table.

1. Is database can handle this? Won't it be slow?
2. It could be make large queries. Is inevitable?

Is there any idea for managing ELO system? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043337/elo-rating-mysql-design) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538572/best-and-most-efficient-way-for-elo-score-calculation-for-users-in-database), however I cannot find other solution.

Comment: Yes, a database can handle this, no problem. And who cares about the size of a piece of SQL? It's the result that counts.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Oh, Thank you for your comment. Now I convinced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate data storage from application processing.

- Use the table to store the data.  Do not try to write ELO algorithms in SQL.
- Since ELO is rather complex, use an application language to compute ELO.  Simply reload the necessary rows (the entire table??), recalculate the rankings, then UPDATE or rebuild the table.

Comment: Currently I had built a table structure like your answer, still it works nicely! I made an elo updater, it triggered every hour to do that delete whole row in table, and create new elo data using match table. I don't know if this is a good method in actual service, but this system isn't bad. Thanks!